# Preventing files uploaded in File Viewer Web part to be automatically added to Sharepoint Documents library

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, asset-library, fileviewer

Whenever I try to upload a file via file viewer web part on Newsfeed page, the file automatically appears in the Default Documents Library. Unfortunately, I do not want this to happen - often these are just unrelated .pdfs that I would rather store in the Site Assets Library. I did go to Advanced Settings and made the Site Assets Library to be the only one set as the main Set Assets Library. I even created a new Documents Library, transferred all the files from the default (previous) documents library one and deleted it. And even after these steps, files uploaded via file viewer web part on newsfeed page, automatically appear on the new Documents library, instead of just the Assets Library. Please help me with this issue as I am unable to find the answers anywhere online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, normally the files added directly from the file viewer web part will be stored in the default Document library.

The Site asset library is used to store some default resources such as pages.

In fact, my suggestion is that since these are irrelevant documents such as Pdfs, you can simply create a new document library, store similar documents in this library, and then select these documents to display in the file viewer.

[image]